# mouseenter and click priority in ipad

Tags: angular, ipad, mouseover

I have a problem with ipad that it's not happening with other tactil devices.

I have a table with "mouseenter" event, and a cell with "click" one.

The problem is I need to click twice the button to get the click event.

```
 <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">


   <ng-container matColumnDef="BUTTON">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> BUTTON </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let v">
           <button mat-icon-button [routerLink]="['/home']">
           </button>
      </mat-cell>
   </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns""></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
     (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (mouseenter)="over(row)"> 
    </mat-row>
   </mat-table>
```

over(row) changes de style to the row, so, the first time I click in button I got the style changed and the second one the routerLink. Is it possible to solve?